# Facebook Like button not working on HTML website

Tags: hyperlink, facebook-like

Hi I have an HTML website, and I am trying to embed a Facebook "Like" button on one of it's pages.  I followed the instructions given, but it does not seem to work.  What I've done as an alternative is place a "like" picture with a hyperlink to my Facebook page.  The person would then have to press the "like" button that is directly on my Facebook page.  Any ideas of why the "like" button does not work when it is embedded directly on my website?

For reference, my website is: http://www.fit-ed.ca/programsF.htm

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: As of now, your website doesn't have a like plugin installed. Instead, you have put a static like button image linked to your Facebook page. So, I can't check what is wrong. If this is what you eventually plan to do, then you can use the thoughts provided in ityler22's response. If this is a stop-gap solution, you need to provide sample code you tried to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the "like button" generator here: [Facebook Like Button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)?

You could also try the "like box" generator which has an option to like the Facebook page but, also displays page activity and status updates. Found here:  [Facebook Like Box](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/)

Could you post the code you were trying to use to embed the like button originally?

If you can provide that, I could look into it more in-depth.